# Flutter GetX calling updated variables in Elevated Button onPressed

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, flutter-getx

I'm new to flutter and am trying to wrap my head around the GetX usage. I've watched a few tutorials and have been searching online for a solution. I'm trying to have a button disabled until 2 variables turn true. In my controller I have a method that I can use to check both variables which in turn changes the bool that I use in another file. I cant seem to find the proper place to use the Obx() method inside the elevatedbutton widget.

```
 class RegistrationController extends GetxController {
      final readTerms = false.obs;
      final readPrivacy = false.obs;
      final enableIntroButton = false.obs;
    
      void isIntroButtonDisabled() {
        if (readTerms.value && readPrivacy.value) {
          enableIntroButton.value = true;
          debugPrint('Button is now enabled');
        }
      }
    }
```

In my startup screen I have created my instance of my controller at the top of my class to use and in my ElevatedButton widget I figured out how to use Obx on the child: property but that same technique doesnt seem to work in the onPressed part

```
ElevatedButton(
                  child: Obx(() => regController.enableIntroButton.value
                      ? Text(
                          'Let\'s Get Started',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        )
                      : Text('Read Terms & Privacy First')),
                  onPressed: () => regController.enableIntroButton.value
                      ? null
                      : Get.to(() => PhoneRegistrationScreen()),
```

The rest of the widget is styling so I didnt include it.

Any help would be great. I just finished learning about stateful widgets and using setState lol. So now having discovered GetX I'm trying to relearn the state management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some trial and error and some more online searching I realized that I needed to clarify the regController.value to be equal to false or true rather then just declaring the variable.

So this was what I had

```
onPressed: () => regController.enableIntroButton.value
                      ? null
                      : Get.to(() => PhoneRegistrationScreen()),
```

and this was what I needed to do...

```
onPressed: () => regController.enableIntroButton.value == false
                      ? null
                      : Get.to(() => PhoneRegistrationScreen()),
```

Although I tried removing the Obx() method right above in the child: property but it didnt seem to work like the onPressed: property so I left it as is.

Comment: Does this fix your problem though? I think you need to wrap your ElevatedButton with Obx(), because it looks like now your onPressed function will not be notified about the changes.

Comment: I did originally try and wrap the whole ElevatedButton in a Obx but I got a error saying I should only be wrapping 1 widget in the method or something along that line. MY full ElevatedButton was pretty packed with other widgets... Not sure if that was what caused the initial error or not at this point. 

The button is now working as I wanted it to though. Thanks for asking